# How to override inc/meta-banner.php in a WordPress child theme

Tags: php, html, wordpress

In the WordPress Parent theme inside the `inc` folder I have `meta-banner.php`, in this php file I have some meta boxes which are include via `inc/meta-function.php` in all posts and pages.

```
add_meta_box('my_all_meta1', 'Banner Details', 'my_meta_banner_setup', $type, 'normal', 'high');

function my_meta_banner_setup() {
  global $post;
  $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_my_meta',TRUE);
  // instead of writing HTML here, lets do an include
  include_once('meta-banner.php');
  // create a custom nonce for submit verification later
  echo '<input type="hidden" name="my_meta_noncename" value="' . wp_create_nonce(__FILE__) . '" />';
}
```

Now I want add/remove some fields in `meta-banner.php` in the child theme. It's not overriding with simple copy paste the file in child theme.

I am not getting how to solve this issue. I have get some answer but not helpful.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the error you are getting i think it says you re-declare function error.

Comment: its not overriding

Comment: we can remove this metabox and create our own metabox in child them did you tried that way ?

Comment: can you please let me know how to do that?

Comment: try to remove with  remove_meta_box( 'my_all_meta1');  and add new meta boxes according to your need